# Framework7 v3 - How to trigger tab show

Tags: html-framework-7

I am using F7 v3 and using tabs, but how can I trigger tab show event?

In the docs it says like this "tab:show" https://framework7.io/docs/tabs.html
 and I try this but does not work

```
  $$('#latest').on('tab:show', function() {
    app.alert('latest is visible');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependence of your code, the error maybe occurred in `app.alert`, so that you need to change it to pure alert or to F7 popup, or maybe the error occurred since you set wrong selector for trigger tab show. please look at this example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/w89xktne/

Html Body:

```
<body>
  <!-- App root -->
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Views/Tabs container -->
    <div class="views tabs">
      <!--
        Tabbar for switching views-tabs. Should be a first child in Views.
        Additional "toolbar-bottom-md" class is also required here for MD theme
      -->
      <div class="toolbar tabbar-labels toolbar-bottom-md">
        <div class="toolbar-inner">
          <a href="#view-home" class="tab-link tab-link-active">1
            <i class="icon icon-home"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#view-catalog" class="tab-link">2
            <i class="icon icon-catalog"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#view-settings" class="tab-link">3
            <i class="icon icon-settings"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Your main view/tab, should have "view-main" class. It also has "tab-active" class -->
      <div id="view-home" class="view view-main tab tab-active">
        Tab 1
      </div>

      <!-- Catalog View -->
      <div id="view-catalog" class="view tab">
        Tab 2
      </div>

      <!-- Settings View -->
      <div id="view-settings" class="view tab">
        Tab 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

app.js:

```
var $$ = Dom7;
var app = new Framework7({
  // App root element
  root: '#app',
  // App Name
  name: 'My App',
  // App id
  id: 'com.myapp.test',
  // Enable swipe panel
  panel: {
    swipe: 'left',
  },
  // Add default routes
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/about/',
      url: 'about.html',
    },
  ],
  // ... other parameters
});

$$('.tab').on('tab:show', function() {
   app.popup.create({
    content: '<div class="popup">'+
              '<div class="block">'+
                '<p>Its Show.</p>'+
                '<p><a href="#" class="link popup-close">Close me</a></p>'+
              '</div>'+
            '</div>',
  }).open();
});
```

Comment: I see now, my alert is the problem. Thank you!!